# Postgres Identifying 2 records with 1 attribute equal and 1 attribute not equal

Tags: postgresql

I am attempting to pull ids of records where attribute a is the same, but attribute b has at least 1 record that does not have a match. The db has >1million records so the statement cannot be absolute but has to change with the data.

i.e in the below I want the result to return id 1, 2 and 3 because a is equal and b is not equal in all instances, and return id 4 and 5

```
ID   A   B

1    y   t
2    y   m
3    y   t
4    z   r
5    z   f
6    q   c
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a way:

```
select
    ID
from
    t t1
where exists (select 1
              from   t t2
              where  t2.A = t1.A
                     and t2.B <> t1.B)
order by
    ID;
```

It could be read as: Give me all ID's if exists another row with same A and different B.

> ```
> | id |
> | -: |
> |  1 |
> |  2 |
> |  3 |
> |  4 |
> |  5 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a51b4e73337686f6d5d54da678f5c018)*